# ASP.NET Binding DataSource to entire page with a single record

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, web-controls

We currently use `asp:Repeater` with `<%#Eval("SomeField")%>` in aspx page to display data.

We would like to use a single record and bind it to a asp.net control on the aspx page so we can `<%#Eval("SomeField")%>`.

I have tried `FormView`, `DetailsView`, and other asp.net controls. All of which required a `.ToList()` or `IEnumerable`. However, we are returning `ctx.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(j => j.ID == id);`

We don't want to use asp:Label or asp:Literal ..

What can we do to use the `<%#Eval("SomeField")%>` in the page when returning a single record?

**PRESENTER**

> ```
>     public static Job GetByID(int id)
>     {
>         using (var ctx= new CareersEntities())
>         {
>             return ctx.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(j => j.ID == id);
>         }
>     }
> ```

**CODE-BEHIND**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Job d = new Job();
        d = JobPresenter.GetByID(ID);

        fvJob.DataSource = d;
        fvJob.DataBind();
}
```

**ASPX PAGE**

> ```
> <asp:FormView  ID="fvJob" runat="server">
>      <ItemTemplate>
>         <%#Eval("Title")%>
>      </ItemTemplate>
> </asp:FormView>
> ```

Comment: Is there any special reason for ruling out using a simple Label? If you have only one record, you bind it directly to the page.

Answer (score 3):

Both `DetailsView` and `FormView` will work with a single object if it's using a data source control (such as ObjectDataSource). With ObjectDataSource you can return a single element from your Select method and the data source will then wrap it in a list just for the sake of the programming interface - but it's not something you'd ever see.

If you want to directly set the control's DataSource property and call DataBind, just wrap the object in an array and then pass that in.

Here's the DetailsView:

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="DetailsView1" AutoGenerateRows="false">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First name:">
            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("FirstName") %></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last name:">
            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("LastName") %></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

And here's the DetailsView binding code in Page_Load:

```
var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
DetailsView1.DataSource = new object[] { person };
DetailsView1.DataBind();
```

Or here's a FormView:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        First name: <%# Eval("FirstName") %><br />
        Last name: <%# Eval("LastName") %><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

And here's the Page_Load code:

```
var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
FormView1.DataSource = new object[] { person };
FormView1.DataBind();
```

And here's the model type (same in both DetailsView and FormView):

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would like to do the binding strictly in code-behind, as I am doing in Repeater. --

Comment: @David I've added a DetailsView sample too.

Comment: see my update, I have added our presenter method that gets the record. When using it directly with the asp:FormView it does not work.

Comment: @David can you clarify what isn't compatible with your question? In my response I show where the model is set in Page_Load - just change that to call your presenter logic and you should be good to go, no?

Comment: This the exact error I am getting: *Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.* --I also add code-behind to question above.

Comment: @David - Understood, so you'll need to wrap it in an array, as I show in my sample code. The object I want to bind to is just one Person object, but it is wrapped in a new object[]{ ... } array to turn it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

A DetailsView requires a List?! Anyhow, why don't you use ctx.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(j => j.ID == id).ToList() ?

Comment: I am trying DetailsVies using:

<asp:DetailsView  ID="fvJob" runat="server">
        <Fields>
            <%#Eval("Title")%>
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>

The EVAL does not work.

Its seems wrong to do Single then .ToList() -- Seems like I am forcing something that should not be.

Comment: You cannot call ToList() on the result of SingleOrDefault(...) (or Single(...) for that matter), as it generally does not return an IEnumerable instance. All data bound controls require an IEnumerable as DataSource (declared on DataBoundControlBase), including DetailsView and FormView.

Comment: I have a method called Cons that takes T and returns IEnumerable<T> for that. What it does is new T[] { param }.